# Big Query command line querying and appending to a table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a script and trying to query a table from within and append the results onto another table.

The command;

```
bq query --destination_table \
'sample_dataset.test_table_formated'$20180518 --append_table \
--use_legacy_sql=true --allow_large_results < sample.txt
```

The error:

```
Error in query string: Error processing job 'abiding-set-202911:bqjob_r31268d48dc7a53b_0000016372fe2604_1':
Encountered " ">=" ">= "" at line 1, column 662.
Was expecting:
")" ...
```

The query stored in sample.txt is below:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT CATS_W_TIMESTAMPS_KEY, SPLIT( VALUES, ",")
   AS VALUES, TAG_URI, PIXEL_URL, REFERRER, CAMPAIGN_ID, WIN_TIME, OBFS_BKUUID, PIXEL_ID, IP_ADDRESS, DATA_DATE, PROCESS_DATE, TRACK_ID
FROM
    (SELECT FIRST(SPLIT(CATS_W_TIMESTAMPS, ":")) AS CATS_W_TIMESTAMPS_KEY, NTH(2, SPLIT(CATS_W_TIMESTAMPS, ":")) AS
      VALUES, TAG_URI, PIXEL_URL, REFERRER, CAMPAIGN_ID, WIN_TIME, OBFS_BKUUID, PIXEL_ID, IP_ADDRESS, DATA_DATE, PROCESS_DATE, TRACK_ID
      FROM
        (SELECT *
         FROM
           (SELECT SPLIT(CATS_W_TIMESTAMPS, ';') AS CATS_W_TIMESTAMPS, TAG_URI, PIXEL_URL, REFERRER, CAMPAIGN_ID, WIN_TIME, OBFS_BKUUID, PIXEL_ID, IP_ADDRESS, DATA_DATE, PROCESS_DATE, TRACK_ID
            FROM [sample_dataset.test_table_1]
            WHERE _PARTITIONTIME>=$PARTITIONDATE )
         GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)))
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13
```

All I want to do is query a table against the pseudo _PARTITIONTIME column, do some operations and append result onto another table.

Can someone please check and let know what error this query has.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in this line :

```
_PARTITIONTIME>=&PARTITIONDATE
```

Try to replace it with:

```
_PARTITIONTIME>=_PARTITIONDATE
```

And i think you have some errors in your bq query line. You also dont need to  --use_legacy_sql=true because that flag is 'true' as default. Try it:

```
bq query --append_table --allow_large_results --destination_table=Dataset.Table "$(cat sample.txt)"
```

Comment: @vasily-bronsky [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool#example) paragraph states that `--use_legacy_sql` is set to `false` by default.